# Display graph foreach element in list c# MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display graph for each element in the list with razor (tried with url.action but nothing worked...)
now, when i'm running on the elements and write a chart, the page displays only on picture, nothing else (not even the body of the page).
does someone know what can i do?
My code:

```
if (analyzeList != null)//list is not null
{
    foreach (var document in analyzeList)//for each record
    {
        i = 0;
        @:<B>documentID : @document._id </B><br />
        foreach (var posture in document.PosturesList)//for each posture, write it
        {
            @:posture - @posture -> @document.DurationsList[i] seconds <br />
            i++;
        }//endforeach posture

        <div>
            @{ 
                new Chart(width: 800, height: 200)//create the chart
                .AddSeries(chartType: "column",
                    xValue: document.PosturesList.AsEnumerable(),//set x values
                    yValues: document.DurationsList.AsEnumerable()).Write();//set y values  
            }
        </div>
                    }//end for each document
                }//end if list is not null
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing just the one chart image because `Chart.Write` method writes the output stream and nothing else will be executed.

You should use an image element and set the source of that as the url to one action method which renders the graph using the Chart api. So create an action method which returns the partial view which has the code for rendering the chart

```
public ActionResult DrawChart()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

And in the `DrawChart.cshtml` view, you will have the code to render the chart image.

Now in your main view you will call this action method and set that as the image `src`

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart", "YourControllerName")" />
```

You may pass the unique id to the `DrawChart` method as query string params to get the data needed for each chart.

```
public ActionResult DrawChart(int documentId)
{
    // to do  : Get data needed to render chart using documentId and pass to the view
    return PartialView();
}
```

and now in the main view , make sure to pass this documentId route value item when using the `Url.Action` helper

```
foreach (var document in analyzeList)//for each record
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart", "YourControllerName",
                                         new { documentId=document._id )" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I pass an object that contains 2 lists to the action result? the object "document"...

Comment: You cannot pass complex objects to the Url.Action helper method. Pass the Id and get the data in the action method using that id and pass it to the view

Comment: awsome! it's working! thanks a lot :) can I update the graphs in live somehow?